# without pressing equal button show the result

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's the full code of my Flutter calculator application with the necessary modifications to automatically calculate result when you enter an expression like "2+3" without pressing the equal button. what should i do for it shares your ideas?

Comment: Code is not Visible here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your code but you can probably update the result by calculating it whenever the textfield calls the onChanged event.